# Visual Studion 2013 Community, Windows Phone 8.1, deployment hangs on HW

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

When I try to deploy an application via "Build Process" to "Device", the following line appears in the Build Log:

1>------ Deploy started: Project: PhoneTrafficLight, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

Then, nothing happens and I do not get any other message during the building and deploying. Visual Studio itself does not hang.

The phone is unlocked (by another computer, but the unlocking tool in Visual Studio on this computer does not give any complaint) and I can deploy an app via "Tools -> Windows Phone 8.1 -> Application Deployment".

On another computer, I get the same problem.

Communication to phone itself seems to work, since I get an error message when the phone is in lock screen or I can request information by other WP 8.1 tools on my computer. When I unplug the USB, I also get a message that the debug connection is interrupted.

I have no clue how to debug this issue.

Comment: I could always solve such problems by rebooting PC or phone. I guess you already did so - if not, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks... rebooting PC helped!

Comment: I see this same problem a lot. Cannot close VS. It says to cancel the build. Asking the build to cancel does not succeed but at least after pressing cancel VS can be closed.